# navigation bar with angularjs with pages divided into segments

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-routing

I have a setup like this

```
<div class="" ng-controller="routeController">
    <nav class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li href="#view1"></li>
            <li href="#view2"></li>
            <li href="#view3"></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div ng-controller="ContentController">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

Now how do I update the angular view of `contentController` view clicks of the navigation bar on top . Cause both controller scopes are different . Any ideas ? I am very very new to angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just have one level menu. You can use `$routeProvider`. Take a look at angular-seed project. It's got a clear example.

app.js

```
// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives', 'myApp.controllers']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/view1', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html', controller: 'MyCtrl1'});
    $routeProvider.when('/view2', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial2.html', controller: 'MyCtrl2'});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
  }]);
```

If you have a multi-level menu, then take a look at this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router and this sample page: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/

Comment: I am already doing that . But the controller scope is in different would that work ?

Comment: It should work, as ng-view gets updated based on the configured route in routeprovider. It is not dependent on controller.

Comment: @Joy change your link to `<li><a href="#/view1">view1</a></li>`, again take a look at the angular-seed project, you can get pretty clear clue of how it works.